# Sens de l'expression 'ce peut-il'

Tags: sens

Voici quelques paroles d'une chanson:

> Ce peut-il que j'y parvienne,
>   Ce peut-il qu'on nous pardonne,
>   Ce peut-il qu'on nous aime pour ce que nous sommes

Quel est le sens de l'expression « ce peut-il » ?

En outre, l'inversion de l'ordre habituel Sujet-Verbe me semble curieuse car il ne s'agit pas d'une question mais d'une affirmation.

P.S.: Feel free to correct my mistakes. Could you give me a heads-up/notification in the comment section on the mistakes I made? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La personne qui a retranscrit les paroles a fait une faute d'orthographe. L'expression est « **Se** peut-il que … ».

« Il se peut que … » signifie « il est possible que … ». Il n'y a pas de différence de sens, mais « il se peut que … » est du langage plutôt soutenu alors que « il est possible que … » est neutre. C'est une construction pronominale du verbe *pouvoir* : le mot *se* est un pronom réfléchi. Plus généralement, on peut dire « X se peut » pour « X est possible », mais c'est rare.

Vu que [les autres vers aux alentours](http://www.paroles-musique.com/paroles-Zazie-A_Ma_Place_avec_Axel_Bauer-lyrics,p6297) sont des questions, il s'agit bien de questions, ce qui explique l'inversion du sujet.

Comment: Gilles, je vous remercie de m'avoir répondu à ma question. Bien que les vers aux alentours soient des questions, les vers dont nous parlons devraient avoir un point d'interrogation pour être des questions. Non?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Ce genre de sites ne se préoccupe ni de l'orthographe ni de la ponctuation, leur contenu n'est pas fiable et ce n'est pas parce qu'il n'y a pas de points d'interrogations qu'il n'en faut pas.